# Cannot find module - relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I wrote a very simple local module to manage a few lines of localized text.
It uses node's `require` to load the language files, but I'm having trouble with paths, most likely.
I'm getting the `Cannot find module` error.

## File structure

```
.
+-- local_modules
|   +-- lang
|   |   +-- package.json
|   |   +-- index.js
+-- locale
|   +-- en.js
|   +-- de.coffee
+-- init.js
+-- index.coffee
+-- package.json
```

## Relevant module code

Should `require` the file if it is not already loaded.

```
join = require('path').join;
_config.path = './locale';
lang = 'en';
_locales = {};

if(!_locales[lang]){
    _locales[lang] = require(join(_config.path, lang));
}
```

Every file in the `locale` directory is a typical Node.js module, for example `en.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    test: 'Hello World!'
};
```

The local module exports a `function(req, res, next){}`, which is used as Express middleware and is supposed
to attach the required object with localized strings onto `res.locals`, however, I'm seeing `Cannot find module 'locale/en'` error.

I've tried to manually add the `.js` extensions (but that shouldn't be neccessary as far as I know).
I have also tried different variations on the path, such as `locale` or `/locale`.

---

The module is called in `index.coffee`.
App is launched using `init.js`, which contains the following:

```
require('coffee-script/register');
require('./index');
```

Maybe it's just that the module is a `.js` (and the module itself doesn't have CoffeeScript as a dependency) so it can not load a `.coffee` file? Although CoffeeScript should be registered globally, or am I wrong? Either way, it doesn't work with the `.js` file either, so I guess it has something to do with paths.

Comment: In my opinion it's better to use next construction: path.join(__dirname, 'locale');
__dirname contain absolute path, and your problem related to relative path. Also you may try to define file extension lang = 'en.js';

Comment: *upd. Just tried locally, path.join resolve './' as '', so use absolute path, or require('./' + join(_config.path, lang));

Comment: With `__dirname`, it is searching inside the module's folder. With `require('./' + join(_config.path, lang));` the result is the same as before (Cannot find module). So, neither works.

Comment: according to documentation __dirname - The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in. Oh, crap, may it be related to 'coffee-script/register'? Can you try to print __dirname value inside index.coffe? It should help to compose correct path.

Comment: @NazarSakharenko When I do `console.log(__dirname);` inside `index.coffee`, it prints the correct folder: `/home/ubuntu/workspace` (this is on C9 machine). When I put the `__dirname` inside the module code, it then tries to acces path `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/lang/locale/en`. Should I pass `__dirname` as argument? But why other modules don't do that? How do regular modules handle paths?

Comment: @NazarSakharenko So I quickly searched through express's view "engine" and saw it using `resolve`. According to docs, `resolve` is used to construct an absolute path. So, using `resolve` instead of `join` actually helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.join()` also normalizes the created path, which *(probably)* means the `./` part was always removed, and what remained was a relative path.

Instead, when `path.resolve()` is used, it creates an absolute path, which is what is needed in this case.